# VS2022 - Annoying Pop-Up for Tab Completetion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Recently reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 and noticed auto-completetion has this annoying pop-up prompting me to use Tab or Tab Tab. This was not there previously. I'd like to ask if there is a way to hide this pop-up without disabling the auto-completion highlight

[image: Popup mentioned]

Comment: Click the little gear on the right in your image and disable it.

Comment: The feature is using a bit of AI to do full line prediction. It can suggest really insightful things to put in your code based on the rest of your codebase. Similar to GitHub Copilot, but with smaller snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sleep deprived brain did not notice when you click the cogwheel there is an option to disabled it. This fixed it

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.